# Custom classes for imags in drupal

Tags: css, drupal-7, colorbox

My basic requirement is to display one picture on a page which on clicking, displays a colorbox slideshow of all the pictures in that content type.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1026112

This is the solution I got for it. To apply display:none css for the rest of the images. For that, I need different classes for the images. I'm unable to figure out how to do so.I got a few solutions such as adding a preprocess_image function but it doesn't seem to work. Can I get some help here?

Answer (score 0):

We did this in past using the "Image sets" option provided with the [Lightbox2](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2) Drupal module. We had a client request to show one image and then open a slideshow on the same page of the images associated with that content in the CMS. This module say:

```
If you have a set of images that you would like to group together in a
lightbox, but only wish for one of these images to be visible on your page, you
can assign the "lightbox_hide_image" class to hide the additional images.  For
example:

<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]">image #1</a>
<a href="images/image-2.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" class="lightbox_hide_image">image #2</a>
<a href="images/image-3.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" class="lightbox_hide_image">image #3</a>
```

You can create a custom node template to render the images in the required format.
Hope this will help you!